# Excel Formula Result is not Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

in Excel i try to get the count of Rows where 2 criterias match. 
I do this with this function 
=COUNT(IF(Data!J$5:Data!J$1000="RC Corp",IF(Data!AD$5:Data!AD$1000="Expected Allowances / Provisions", 1)))

Data is here a different Worksheet in my Workbook. In the cell it shows me the Result 1.
But when i watch the Formula, it tells me "Formula Result = 2" the correct result is 2. But it always shows 1. 
I also tried to update the cell manually with f9 but nothing changes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Excel 2007+ use
        =COUNTIFS(Data!J$5:Data!J$1000,"RC Corp",Data!AD$5:Data!AD$1000,"Expected Allowances / Provisions")

For Older then 2007 use 
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!D:D="RC Corp")*(Data!AD:AD="Expected Allowances / Provisions"))

Comment: Thanks, for the fast replay, but sadly I get an error with this Forumal, it says that it contains errors. I think you wanted to offer the COUNTIF formula but also this wont work. COUNTIF only allows 2 Parameter, the Range and the Criteria.

Comment: What Version of Excel are you trying i tried this formula and it worked perfect in 2007 and 2010

Comment: we use excel2003 in our company.

Comment: You have have a version from 2000-2003 Then try =SUMPRODUCT((Data!D:D="RC Corp")*(Data!AD:AD="Expected Allowances / Provisions"))